# Get total number of 1s from runs of 1 in every sliding window

Tags: r, sliding-window

I have a dataset where:

```
df <- data.frame(row_id = c(100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109),
         row_id2 = c(1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000),
         col1 = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0),
         col2 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
         col3 = c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0),
         col4 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1),
         col5 = c(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1))
```

I have to transpose the table, and then add a new column `pos` to assign each row with a `col` prefix with a numerical value:

```
library(data.table)
df_tr<-transpose(df)
rownames(df_tr)<-colnames(df)
df_tr$pos<-c("NA","NA",1000,1156,4629,8208,10000)

|       |  V1    V2    V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9   V10   pos|
|row_id |  100   101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108   109    NA|
|row_id2| 1000  2000  3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000   NA|
|col1   |    1     0    1    1    1    0    0    1    1     0  1000|
|col2   |    1     1    1    0    0    1    1    1    0     0  1156|
|col3   |    0     0    1    0    0    1    1    1    1     0  4629|
|col4   |    1     1    1    0    0    1    0    1    1     1  8208|
|col5   |    1     1    1    0    1    0    1    0    0     1 10000|
```

Using the values from `pos`, for each column, I want to use sliding windows of size 2000, sliding by 1000 at a time, to get the total number of 1s from runs of 1 in each window. (I want to exclude standalone 1s). The window sliding would start at 1000, corresponding to `col1` and end at 10000, corresponding to `col5`.

I want to create a separate table where the first and second columns would be `row_id`, `row_id2`, and then a column corresponding to each sliding window would follow.

For example, the final output for the first few rows would be:

```
|row_id |row_id2 |window1 |window2 |window3 |window4 |window5 |window6 |window7 |window8 |
| 100   |  1000  |   2    |   0    |   0    |  0     |   0    |  0     |  0     |   2    |
| 101   |  2000  |   0    |   0    |   0    |  0     |   0    |  0     |  0     |   2    |
| 102   |  3000  |   2    |   0    |   0    |  0     |   0    |  0     |  0     |   2    |
| 103   |  4000  |   0    |   0    |   0    |  0     |   0    |  0     |  0     |   0    |
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `?rle` is gonna be helpful

Comment: Your code doesn't make the input object shown.  the data.table::transpose function creates a list and lists don't have rownames.

Comment: @BrianMontgomery im not exactly sure what you mean, i just assigned the colnames from the original table as the rownames in the transposed table . when i print `df_tr` i get the table as shown in my question

Comment: My fault - I was accidentally running purrr::transpose and getting a list.

Comment: Can't really understand what you are attempting???  Using the values from pos (for what purpose?), for each column, I want to use sliding windows of size 2000, sliding by 1000 at a time, to get the total number of 1s from runs of 1 in each window. (I want to exclude standalone 1s). The window sliding would start at 1000 (if your 2000 row window starts at 1000, how can it end at 10000?) , corresponding to col1 and end at 10000, corresponding to col5.  What???

Comment: @Jim i meant that since the `pos` value for `col1` and `col5` is 1000 and 10000 respectively, if my window size is 2000 sliding/step by 1000 at a time, the windows would be: [1000, 3000], [2000, 4000], [3000,5000], ... , [8000, 10000]. i want to get the count of 1s in each window only if they appear back to back like 1,1,1 would be three 1s and 1,0,1 would be zero 1s in a given window.

Comment: Your example says col1 is 1000 and col5 is 10000.   How did you pick col1 and col5 and is there any significance to those two columns?  Which column or columns should the window be applied to?  My choice? I understand sequential (back-to-back) and slices of 2000, but little else.  How can you break the 9000 increment interval between 1000 and 10000 into 2000 unit slices?

Comment: @Jim in the dataset im working with, col1 here would represent the starting position and col5 would represent the ending position. the positions of all the other cols in between col1 and col5 are randomly distributed as shown in my question. the sliding window would apply to the `pos` column, for ex. for column V1, i want R to recognize that in the first window,  [1000, 3000], there are two 1s because col1 and col2 have a 1, and col1 `pos` is 1000, col2 `pos` is 1156, so they belong in the window, but col3 `pos` is 4629, so it's not included in the first window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `pos` to make it numeric.
I also converted df_tr to a data.table to make it easier to work with.
The final answer is still a data.frame.

```
df_tr$pos<-c(NA_real_,NA_real_,1000,1156,4629,8208,10000)

setDT(df_tr)
window_list <- vector('list')
for (i in 1:8) {
  window_list[[i]] <- 
    df_tr[!is.na(df_tr$pos) & df_tr$pos %between% c(1000 * i, 1000 * i + 2000), 
          sapply(.SD, \(x) {
            y <- rle(x)
            z <- y[['lengths']][y[['values']] == 1]
            sum(z[z > 1])
          }), .SDcols = patterns('V')]
}
ans <- cbind(df[, 1:2], do.call('cbind', window_list))
setnames(ans, as.character(1:8), paste0('window', 1:8))
ans <- `rownames<-`(ans, NULL)
ans
   row_id row_id2 window1 window2 window3 window4 window5 window6 window7
1     100    1000       2       0       0       0       0       0       0
2     101    2000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
3     102    3000       2       0       0       0       0       0       0
4     103    4000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
5     104    5000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
6     105    6000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
7     106    7000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
8     107    8000       2       0       0       0       0       0       0
9     108    9000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
10    109   10000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
   window8
1        2
2        2
3        2
4        0
5        0
6        0
7        0
8        0
9        0
10       2
```